# Newbie php question with hashing passwords and user login

Tags: php, mysql, hash

Here is my create account mysql query. For the sake of ease I have left out salting.

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (username, email, password) 
                      VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$q -> execute(array($_POST['username'], $_POST['email']
                        ,hash('sha256', $_POST['password'])));
```

Which does what I want, inserts a hashed password into the database, now my login script;

```
if ($count == 1 && $info['password'] === hash('sha256', $_POST['password']) 
                && $info['logcount'] != -1) { // successful login
```

This statement always returns false, I have tried different operates ie (=, ==), I am sure it is a simple solution.

Also if you have any good salting techniques please share :)

Thanks.

Comment: On a sidenote: [A little reading on hashing passwords](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html).

Comment: This has been bookmarked great link thanks.

Comment: Did you `print_r($info)` and `echo hash('sha256', $_POST['password'])`?

Comment: (($count == 1) && ($info['password'] == hash('sha256', $_POST['password'])) 
                && ($info['logcount'] != -1))) *pressed enter too soon*

Comment: Ok I'll try that now, thanks Johan :)

Comment: @kakoa no I only ever use echo, if that matters? I thought stick to one or the other, I prefer echo.

Comment: @Johan no luck, this has baffled me, I have used this method over and over, maybe it has something to do with PDO?

Comment: Try using sha2('password') instead of hash('sha256','password').

Answer (score -1):

Why do you make type checking with ===? Maybe just

```
$info['password'] == hash('sha256', $_POST['password'])
```

?

Comment: Read the question it says: `I have tried different operates ie (=, ==),`

Comment: For php hash salts see the question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords